# My program is not running as i want it to. Does not detect the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and my code isn't working correctly.
I put the code in the same directory as the text file 'hw.txt'

The pastebin here for the txt: https://pastebin.com/vXuKeFCM

The program is supposed to take the average of the 11 numbers and drop the lowest number. Then print the average of grade. While having exception handling. But it just keeps skipping and goes directly to the except line. Even though the files are in the same place.

```
#Welcome/Introduction Message
print("This program will read all the grades from the hw.txt file.")
print("Then the program wll calculate the final homework grade(average with the lowest grade dropped.")
print()

#TRY/ELSE/IF/STRUCTURE
try:
    file = open("hw.txt", "r")
    i = 0
    minGrade = 0
    total = 0
    for line in file:
        if i == 0:
            minGrade = int(line)
        else:
            if minGrade > int(line):
                minGrade= int(line)
        total = total + int(line)
        i = i + 1
    average = (total - minGrade)/(i-1)
    print("average final home grade:", average)
except:
    print("File cannot open or be found. Try troubleshooting.")
```

Comment: If you're having a problem, I suggest removing the `try`/`except` statements so that you get a full traceback of whatever exception is being hit. It may not be related to finding the file at all. In general, it's a bad idea to have a bare `except` block that catches everything, since it might catch exceptions you don't expect, hiding bugs you would otherwise be able to fix.

Comment: In addition to using specific exceptions with `except`, put as little code in the `try` block as you can. In your case, you are really only checking whether the `open` succeeded, so that's all that should be under `try`.

Comment: Some things that might be causing exceptions in your code: Calling `int` on something non-numeric (you'd get a `ValueError`). Dividing by `(i-1)` if `i` is 1 (you'd get a `ZeroDivisionError`). The file not found case would raise a `FileNotFoundError`, if you want to catch only that.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `try`, you will get this message

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '84.5\n'`

As you can see, 84.5 can't be properly parsed because its a double not a int. you need to parse it into a float

Also, having a `try except` with no specific exception is very evil. You will silence ALL exception instead of only the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here's how you could restructure your code so that only `open` is in the `try` block.  Note the use of the `else` block to indicate the code that should be executed if no error occurred.

```
#Welcome/Introduction Message
print("This program will read all the grades from the hw.txt file.")
print("Then the program wll calculate the final homework grade(average with the lowest grade dropped.")
print()

#TRY/ELSE/IF/STRUCTURE
try:                  # try only to open the file
    file = open("hw.txt", "r")
except IOError:       # use a reasonably specific exception type
    print("File cannot open or be found. Try troubleshooting.")
else:                 # if no error occurred
    i = 0
    minGrade = 0
    total = 0
    for line in file:
        if i == 0:
            minGrade = int(line)
        else:
            if minGrade > int(line):
                minGrade= int(line)
        total = total + int(line)
        i = i + 1
    average = (total - minGrade)/(i-1)
    print("average final home grade:", average)
```

This will quickly reveal to you the actual problem (which is as noted by Bobby).

Answer (score -1):

The main reason you're getting this error is because ***file*** is a keyword in Python so it's common practice to use ***f*** for the file variable instead.

In addition, if you change the file variable, you'll still have issues with int().  Why are you using int() to convert the values?  Are you wanting to round up or down?  Assuming you don't want to round, we can simply use float() to get the values needed.

Also, don't forget to close the file!  Here's a suggestion:

```
#Welcome/Introduction Message
print("This program will read all the grades from the hw.txt file.")
print("Then the program wll calculate the final homework grade(average with the lowest grade dropped.")
print()

#TRY/ELSE/IF/STRUCTURE
try:
    f = open("hw.txt", "r")
    i = 0
    minGrade = 0
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        if i == 0:
            minGrade = float(line)
        else:
            if minGrade > float(line):
                minGrade= float(line)
        total = total + float(line)
        i = i + 1
    average = (total - minGrade)/(i-1)
    print("average final home grade:", average)
except:
    print("File cannot open or be found. Try troubleshooting.")
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: `file` is not a keyword in Python. It's a built-in name in Python 2 (and can be reassigned without error, like any built-in name) but it's not used for anything in Python 3.

Comment: That's the correction.  However, when reassigning in Python 2, I was getting `file not found` errors.  The second I switched the assignment to `f`, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: That can't cause that problem.

Comment: You're right, not entirely sure what the issue was as I completely blew away that test directory.  Thanks for the clarification! Now I'm embarrassed.. :(